# What is a good practice to receive POST (Push Notifications) from an API to a Laravel application?

Tags: php, laravel, push-notification, laravel-5

I have an API that sends push notifications to my Laravel application. Basically it needs an URL so he can POST the notifcations.

Where should I make this file? Where and how can I process the information in my app? (regarding Laravel best practices)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can search for payload pass in api. you will get an idea about it.